# How to compile ts code with some method, which is not declared in d.ts file, but this one is in js file?

Tags: typescript

I am using definition ts file, but this one does not contain a method, which I should use in my TypeScript code. However this method is defined in javascript file.

TypeScript compiler writes that it can not find called method.

Is it possible to compile typescript code with some method, which is not declared yet in definition ts file, but this method is defined in javascript file?

Maybe I can set some settings to compile typescript code with call of the method, which is not declared in d.ts file?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you are looking for are `Ambient Internal/External Modules`: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-working-with-other-javascript-libraries

For example:

```
declare module D3 {
    export interface Selectors {
        select: {
            (selector: string): Selection;
            (element: EventTarget): Selection;
        };
    }

    export interface Event {
        x: number;
        y: number;
    }

    export interface Base extends Selectors {
        event: Event;
    }
}
```

You can put this code to your `.ts` file or you can create your own `.d.ts` file.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what d.ts (library you are using).

TypeScript namespaces (aka modules) and interfaces are open ended - it means you can declare missing method directly in you code (without changing external d.ts).

Or you can type the library to `any` when calling missing method - then no type check are done on the library/variable.

```
var a = (<any>$).missingMethod();
```

Comment: Thank you, @ahz I added into external d.ts missed required method. It is a temp solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use at the top of your file `/// <reference path="path/file.ts" />` to get some tips from your IDE (at least in Visual Studio) about what is available in that file and also need to include it in your bundle or add your script in your html file, include it before the other ts file that use its method.